# How do I load (or reshape) my data to input into an LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am following this LSTM Model: [https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-rnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/#:~:text=(scores)-,Complete%20Example,-Now%20that%20we](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-rnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/#:%7E:text=(scores)-,Complete%20Example,-Now%20that%20we)

All my extracted features, labels of train and test set and the LSTM models are in the same folder.

LSTM requires 3D tensors = [samples, timesteps, fetaures]. But my `train_features.csv` file is 2D (i.e. 9000 x 861). How do I restructure it to pass it onto LSTM? Also, do I directly one-hot encode the features csv?

My `train_labels.csv` is 9000 x 1

My directory is as follows:

```
├── published_data
│   ├── labels
│   │   ├── 1_ann.csv
│   │   ├── 2_ann.csv
│   │   └── (25 files of labels)
│   ├── skeletal_keypoints
│   │   ├── 1_keypoint.csv
│   │   ├── 2_keypoint.csv
│   │   └── (25 files of skeletal data)
│   └── video
│       ├── 1.mts
│       ├── 2.mts
│       └── (25 video files)
└── Models
    └── LSTM
        ├── extract_data_LSTM.py
        ├── test_features.csv
        ├── test_ids.csv
        ├── test_labels.csv
        ├── train_features.csv
        ├── train_ids.csv
        ├── train_labels.csv
        └── LSTM_model.ipynb
```

Comment: The web page you link to  says (I think) that the training data should be a size 561 vector for each of 128 time steps for each training point. That sounds good for directly using in an LSTM, but doesn't correspond to the data dimensions you've quoted in your question.

Comment: You have to build windows, e.g. with a window of size 128 for each label, have not only the corresponding datapoint in x,  but the last 128 datapoints, each with its feature vector. In the link, they build a window of 128, and have a 50% overlap between the windows. Windows can overlap at min `windows - 1` points (move one label along), or you jump labels (in the link examle, jump 64 labels/data for the new window).

Comment: @mhenning If I create windows for each label (for activity recognition in this case), I end up with windows of various sizes. Is there any way to vary the time steps for each label?

Comment: Yes https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/understanding_masking_and_padding